# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Musical Practice & Performance Stack Exchange](http://music.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [More volume from a Bass Clarinet](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20700/more-volume-from-a-bass-clarinet)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Learning the musical concepts in the book "Gödel, Escher, Bach"](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22216/learning-the-musical-concepts-in-the-book-g%c3%b6del-escher-bach)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What's the difference between genre and style?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/21936/whats-the-difference-between-genre-and-style)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Stress in music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22303/stress-in-music)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [How to put PA speaker so I can't get any feedback?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/how-to-put-pa-speaker-so-i-cant-get-any-feedback)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Instruments that challenge your ear](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22257/instruments-that-challenge-your-ear)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Lower guitar tuning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20748/lower-guitar-tuning)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 14, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Solution for guitar play with backing track](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20817/solution-for-guitar-play-with-backing-track)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Headphones for musicians](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22018/headphones-for-musicians)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [What Android app is most-used for reading music on the bandstand in these circumstances?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/22051/what-android-app-is-most-used-for-reading-music-on-the-bandstand-in-these-circum)

**Net Score: -9** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 10)

---

Answer (score 1):

I thought @KevinJohnsrude's [question](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/22051/9198) about android apps for reading sheet music was pretty useful, but it only got one answer, and it doesn't show up via Google easily at all. And, a lot of other useful info about this subject *does* show up easily on Google.

Comment: I agree. It would be great if other apps were represented as answers, and get voting for the usefulness of those apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think [How to put PA speaker so I can't get any feedback?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/20828/how-to-put-pa-speaker-so-i-cant-get-any-feedback) is pretty good in terms of question and answers, but I couldn't get google to show it (unless stating it like in the title). Should maybe be re-phrased to use "avoid" or similar terms.

Comment: Yep, exactly the same here, so I gave it satisfactory...